# How to manage visibility in multiple Observable calls?

Tags: json, angular, observable

I developped an Angular2 service to retrieve a list a categories from a backend server and count how many 'links' exist per category.
Once I have the number of links for each category, I add a property to the Json object to 'store' the value.

Here is the code:

```
nbLinks = '';

...

getCategories() {
        return this.category.find({where: {clientId: this.userApi.getCurrentId()}}).map((data) => {
                this.categoriesList = data;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.categoriesList.length; i++) {
                    var obj = this.categoriesList[i].id;
                    this.category.countLinks(obj).subscribe((linksCount) => {
                        this.nbLinks = linksCount;

                    }, err => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                }
                return data;
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        );
```

I am getting the categories in a json object with the correct 'where' clause.
I am looping on the Json to 'count' the number of link in this category.

My problem is that outside the for loop (getting out) **the variable i** is bigger than my Json length so the app is crashing.
My second problem is that I do not have the visiblity of this.nbLinks outside the for ... loop.

Thanks an Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your code, but two things stand out:

**1) It looks like you're mixing synchronous and asynchronous code. It cannot work.**

Sync code: the `for` loop. Async code: the observable.

Instead, could you refactor your code to ONLY work with observables and chain all the operations? You can wrap any piece of data in an observable with `Observable.from()` or `Observable.of()`.

For instance:

```
getCategories() {
  const categories = this.category.find({where: {clientId: this.userApi.getCurrentId()}});
  return Observable.from(categories)
           .map(category => countLinksInCategory(category));
}
```

If `countLinksInCategory()` is an async operation, then have that function return an Observable, and use `.mergeMap()` instead of `.map()` in the code above.

**2) Try avoiding setting an outside variable from within your observable**

```
// This part is not ideal
Obs.subscribe(linksCount => {
  this.nbLinks = linksCount;
});
```

I would suggest renaming `getCategories()` to `getNumLinks()` to reflect the role of the function. The only job of the Observable inside this function is to **produce a value**. Then, the **consumer** of the Observable can use that value (i.e. assign it, display it...).

In terms of code:

```
getNumLinks(): Observable<number> {
  // Here, count the number of links - See example code above.
  // Eventually, return an observable wrapping the final value.
}
```

Then, elsewhere in your code:

```
// This is where you assign the value returned by the Observable.
// Note that we are OUTSIDE the Observable now.
getNumLinks().subscribe(numLinks => this.nbLinks = numLinks);
```

Comment: In fact my function getCategories() role is to return a Json object build from data coming from both **category** and **links** that are API models. I totally agree with you that my problem comes from synchronous and asynchronous code mixed together.

Comment: I just modified the code to:

        **'getCategories() {
            const categories = this.category.find({where: {clientId: this.userApi.getCurrentId()}});
            return Observable.from(categories).mergeMap(category => this.category.countLinks(category));
    };'**
and receive an error : 

   **"MODEL_NOT_FOUND" message:"could not find a model with id [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" name:"Error"**

The countLinks() function needs an Id as a parameter and not an object as we count the number of links for a particular categoryId

Comment: If you can provide a JsFiddle of your code, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I am completely rewriting things now and reading further information about observables. If needed I will provide a fidle and if I succeed making this work, I will publish my code here. Merci

Comment: impossible to create a plunk as I am using a SDK. To resume, the countLinks() function take an id as a parameter  **countLinks(categoryId)** and returns an observable. The getCategories() function returns an observable and is called via **getCategories(UserID)**. I have no problem getting all the categories from a particular user. I just need for each item of the observable returned by the getCategories() function make a linkCount(categoryId) and stored everything somewhere to be accessed in my component.

Comment: So you want to plug the values emitted by the first observable `getCategories()` into a second observable `countLinks()`, correct?

Comment: I this this is correct. getCategories(userID) returns an Observable containing all categories of a particular User. On each category (he Observable is a list of categories), I want to execute countLink(categoryID), with categoryId (returned by the 1st Observable). CountLink() also returns an Observable. I would like to have a result in an array (Observable?). I thought adding a property to the first Array (the one returned by getCategories(userId)).

Comment: Sounds like a good fit for the [mergeMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap). Again, this would be A LOT easier to demonstrate with a working Plnkr.

Comment: Hello, I created a Plnkr with the 3 files (HTML, Component and service). Of course they do not work but it show what i intend to do. Thanks for your patiene and your help : https://plnkr.co/edit/i7Gqhx9zm7QUCRLL9977?p=info